# Error 403 after @EnableOAuth2Sso in Spring security

Tags: spring, post, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I've got my own mapping `setCred/` and when it gets called via a http `POST` request it returns a 403 Error. But when I remove the `@EnableOAuth2Sso` it all works fine.
I don't have any idea what part I'm missing here.

```
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@Controller
public class TestAPI {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/setCred", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "text/plain")
    public ResponseEntity<?> setCred(@RequestBody StringToken json) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
            ResponseEntity<?> res = null;
....
```

My end goal is to add a `facebook login` on my webpage (from https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/)

I've got also `security.basic.enabled=false` in my `application.properties`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
}
```

Starting with Spring Security 4.0 CSRF protection is enabled by default, I removed it for now, at the time my front end is not handling any CSRF tokens. But in the future I'll make sure to include a CSRF token within each POST request. Of course depending on one's intentions `CSRF` may be or not enabled, the only "bad" part about enabling the `CSRF` is adding more complexity to our code.